# Does nuclearity in a rigged Hilbert space have something to do with entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

For extending the Dirac notation to the continuous spectrum we need to introduce a rigged Hilbert space $(\mathcal S,\mathcal H,\mathcal S')$ where $\mathcal S$ must have some particular properties in order to form an *appropriate* rigged Hilbert space.

In particular we require $\mathcal S$ to be a [nuclear space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space). I'm trying to understand why we physically need this request (and honestly I don't understand a lot of the math in the Wiki page). It looks like a nuclear space is somehow connected to the definition of tensor products, so I'm wondering if this has something to do with entanglement and Hilbert spaces of composite systems.

Anyhow, I'm asking if someone could explain in the language of Physics what the nuclearity request is necessary for.

Comment: There are no subsystems here (we already have observables with continuous spectrum for a single particle), so how would entanglement enter into this? Why do you think there is a *physical* necessity for nuclear spaces rather than a *mathematical* one? Physicists rarely care about the subtlety that the $\lvert x\rangle$ don't live in the actual Hilbert space to begin with.

Comment: There is no such thing as mathematical necessity. Mathematically you could build another kind of rigged Hilbert spaces whithout the nuclearity request, for instance. But physically we don't do that, thus we need nuclearity in order for things to work. I don't know why and this is exactly what my question is about.

Comment: There is no physical argument I have ever read to require that the RHS contain a nuclear locally convex TVS. The RHS is useful to solve spectral equations which have no solutions in a separable HS. Also it gives a mathematical justification to the Dirac's formalism, alongside van Eijndhoven's theory of trajectory spaces.